# Best way to make collage like page fully responsive?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have collage like landing page... something like this:

[image]

Each object on this page is a separate image - wrapped in an absolute positioned div.

Now my goal is to make this page fully responsive. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: it will be hard work :) but http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ can help

Comment: There a few ways to approach this, media queries will allow you to have css for different screen sizes then you can change/scale and re-position the images for each screen size you want to support.

Comment: do you set your picture on a grid ? wich are img and wich is background ? SVG + a + pattern/fill could do.

Comment: @GCyrillus as you see from the picture, each image is "randomly" positioned, so there is no option for a grid. All images are in content (not in CSS as a background).

Answer (score 1):

For a layout like this, I'd make the absolute positions percentage scaled, the widths of the images percentage scaled plus get the images centred on their absolute positions by using negative percentage margins (equal to half the percentage width).  Also use percentage font-sizes.  If you do that, I think the  whole thing should scale more or less like it was one image.  Then you can use media queries sparingly to hide things or make the layout different at breakpoints if necessary.

Here's an example:

```
  #collage-item {
    top: 20.3%;
    left: 34%;
    width: 2.1%;
    height: 1.89%;
    margin-left: -1.05%;
    margin-top: -0.945%;
    font-size: 50%;
  }
```

Comment: James, can you explain a little more what you mean by "I'd make the absolute positions percentage scaled, the widths of the images percentage scaled plus get the images centred on their absolute positions by using negative percentage margins (equal to half the percentage width).". Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully the above example I edited into the answer will make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to look at some CSS Frameworks to help you achieve this, 2 spring to mind

1) [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
2) [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Though there are many more out there I like these two as they are very easy to customise.

Comment: Well, I'm familiar with Twitter Bootstrap (suppose Zurb is similar), but they are good for trivial scenarios. I don't see how I can use Bootstrap in my case :(

Comment: @todo you can just use the parts on Bootstrap you want, so why not just use the basic framework layout, like your col-md-4, col-md-12 etc etc and media queries, theres no easy solution for this though

Comment: as you see from the picture, each image is "randomly" positioned, so there is no option for the Bootstrap col-md-xx grid system.

Comment: how are "absolute" positioned images "Randomly" positioned..you need structure IMHO, nothing is just placed randomly

Comment: what I mean by "randomly" is that no image is exactly above or besides another image. Each image is with different offset.top and offset.left. Grid is more like a table, where for example - everything placed in column 2 shares the same offset.left... Do you get what I mean?